# How can I track references to Perl objects?

Tags: perl, memory-management

I'm trying to fix my code to enable Perl to recover unneeded data by weakening references and breaking cycles.

I recently asked a question on [How to access Perl ref counts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276885/how-can-i-access-the-ref-count-of-a-perl-hash) and the answer has been working well for me.

For some of my objects, the reference count is > 1 and I don't know why.

Is there a way for me to add a callback or something to help me know when a reference count is incremented? I want to know who is referencing an object.

Comment: `weaken` is not implemented as "decrement the reference count", weak references are their own thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implement a `Devel::XXX` package that inspects the refcounts of your objects?

```
package Devel::Something;
# just emulating Devel::Trace here
# see http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/MJD/Devel-Trace-0.10/Trace.pm
sub DB::DB {
    if ($Devel::Something::CHECK) {
        my ($package, $file, $linenumber) = caller;
        ... inspect current refcounts
        ... if any have changed, print out the details
        ...    including current package/file/linenumber
        $Devel::Something::CHECK = 0;  # disable until it's enabled again
    }
}
1;
```

---

```
# my program
... do some stuff ...
$Devel::Something::CHECK = 1;
... do some more stuff ...
$Devel::Something::CHECK = 1;
```

---

```
$ perl -d:Something my_program.pl ...
```

You could sprinkle `$Devel::Something::CHECK = 1` statements at appropriate places throughout your code, or change the condition in `DB::DB` to run at regular intervals (e.g., `if (++$Devel::Something::CHECK % 100 == 0) {` to inspect after every 100 statement evaluations).

Answer (score 0):

Perl values only keep track of their weaken references, not their hard ones. There seems to be no way to add a callback for such a think. You'll have to check the refcounts yourself and do your math from that.