# what is the difference between taking reference to a variable using \ and {},[] in perl?

Tags: perl

below code works fine but if I replace `push @array,{%hash}` with `push @array,\%hash` then it doesn't. Can someone please help me understand the difference. I believe `{%hash}` refers to an anonymous hash. Does it mean a anonymous hash lives longer than a reference to a named hash ( `\%hash` ).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
my @array;
my %hash;
%hash = ('a' => 1,
         'b' => 2,
         'c' => 3,);

push @array,{%hash};

%hash = ('e' => 1,
         'f' => 2,
         'd' => 3,);

push @array,{%hash};

print Dumper \@array;
```

**output**

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'c' => 3,
            'a' => 1,
            'b' => 2
          },
          {
            'e' => 1,
            'd' => 3,
            'f' => 2
          }
        ];
```

**UPDATE**
Below is the actual code I am working on. I think in this case taking copy of the reference is the only possible solution I believe. Please correct me if I am wrong.

```
use Data::Dumper;
use strict;
use warnings;

my %csv_data;
my %temp_hash;
my @cols_of_interest = qw(dev_file test_file diff_file status);
<DATA>; #Skipping the header
while (my $row = <DATA>) {
    chomp $row;
    my @array = split /,/,$row;
    @temp_hash{@cols_of_interest} = @array[3..$#array]; 
    push @{$csv_data{$array[0]}{$array[1] . ':' . $array[2]}},{%temp_hash};
}
print Dumper \%csv_data;

__DATA__
dom,type,id,dev_file,test_file,diff_file,status
A,alpha,1234,dev_file_1234_1.txt,test_file_1234_1.txt,diff_file_1234_1.txt,pass
A,alpha,1234,dev_file_1234_2.txt,test_file_1234_2.txt,diff_file_1234_2.txt,fail
A,alpha,1234,dev_file_1234_3.txt,test_file_1234_3.txt,diff_file_1234_3.txt,pass
B,beta,4567,dev_file_4567_1.txt,test_file_4567_1.txt,diff_file_4567_1.txt,pass
B,beta,4567,dev_file_4567_2.txt,test_file_4567_2.txt,diff_file_4567_2.txt,fail
C,gamma,3435,dev_file_3435_1.txt,test_file_3435_1.txt,diff_file_3435_1.txt,pass
D,hexa,6768,dev_file_6768_1.txt,test_file_6768_1.txt,diff_file_6768_1.txt,fail
```

Comment: See [perldoc perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) and [perldoc perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.htm) ... Perl comes with extensive and very useful documentation. Use it.

Comment: It would make more sense to just make your `%temp_hash` lexical inside of the loop and then use a regular reference. You're making your life hard because you're using the short but hard to read syntax, but have to bend over backwards to get it to work. If the cols never change, just do `push @{$csv_data{$array[0]}}{...}, { dev_file => $array[3], test_file => $array[4] .. }`. That's way easier to read if indented nicely.

Comment: Sorry, but now I am again confused. making %temp_hash lexical inside the loop and using a regular reference does work but then how does the data lives though I keep on overwriting new values to %temp_hash through the loop.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both `\%hash` and `{%hash}` create *references*, but they reference two different things.

`\%hash` is a ref to `%hash`. If dereferenced, its values will change with the values in `%hash`.

`{%hash}` creates a new anonymous hash reference from the values in `%hash`. It creates a **copy**. It's the simplest way of creating a [shallow copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copying#Shallow_copy) of a data structure in Perl. If you alter `%hash`, this copy is not affected.

---

How long a variable lives has nothing to do with what kind the variable is, or how it was created. Only the [*scope*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)) is relevant for that. References in Perl are a special case here, because there is an internal ref counter that keeps track of references to a value, so that it is kept alive if there are still references around somewhere even if it goes out of scope. That's why this works:

```
sub frobnicate {
    my %hash = ( foo => 'bar' );
    return \%hash;
}
```

If you want to disassociate the reference from the initial value, you need to turn it into a [*weak reference*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_reference) via `weaken` from [Scalar::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar/Util.html#weaken). That way, the ref count will not be influenced by it, but it will still be related to the value, while a copy would not be.

See [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) and [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) for more information on references. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2276885/1331451) deals with how to see the ref count. A description for that is also available in the chapter [*Reference Counts and Mortality* in perlguts](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlguts.html#Reference-Counts-and-Mortality).

Answer (score 3):

You can't really compare `\` to `{}` and `[]` since they don't do the same thing at all.

`{ LIST }` is short for `my %anon = LIST;  \%anon`

`[ LIST ]` is short for `my @anon = LIST;  \@anon`

---

Maybe you meant to compare

1. ```
   my %hash = ...;
   push @a, \%hash;
   ```
2. ```
   push @a, { ... };
   ```
3. ```
   my %hash = ...;
   push @a, { %hash };
   ```

The first snippet places a reference to `%hash` in `@a`. This is presumably found in a loop. As long as `my %hash` is found in the loop, a reference to a new hash will be placed in `@a` each time.

The second snippet does the same, just using an anonymous hash.

The third snippet makes a copy of `%hash`, and places a reference to that copy in `@a`. It gives the impression of wastefulness, so it's discouraged. (It's not actually not that wasteful because it allows `%hash` to be reused.)

---

You could also write your code

```
# In reality, the two blocks below are probably the body of one sub or one loop.

{
   my %hash = (
      a => 1,
      b => 2,
      c => 3,
   );

   push @a, \%hash;
}

{
   my %hash = (
      d => 3,
      e => 1,
      f => 2,
   );

   push @a, \%hash;
}
```

or

```
push @a, {
   a => 1,
   b => 2,
   c => 3,
};

push @a, {
   d => 3,
   e => 1,
   f => 2,
};
```

---

```
my @cols_of_interest = qw( dev_file test_file diff_file status );

my %csv_data;
if (defined( my $row = <DATA> )) {
    chomp $row;
    my @cols = split(/,/, $row);

    my %cols_of_interest = map { $_ => 1 } @cols_of_interest;
    my @cols_to_delete = grep { !$cols_of_interest{$_} } @cols;

    while ( my $row = <DATA> ) {
        chomp $row;
        my %row; @row{@cols} = split(/,/, $row);
        delete @row{@cols_to_delete};
        push @{ $csv_data{ $row{dev_file} }{ "$row{test_file}:$row{diff_file}" } }, \%row;
    }
}
```

Better yet, let's use a proper CSV parser.

```
use Text::CSV_XS qw( );

my @cols_of_interest = qw( dev_file test_file diff_file status );

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({
    auto_diag => 2,
    binary    => 1,
});

my @cols = $csv->header(\*DATA);

my %cols_of_interest = map { $_ => 1 } @cols_of_interest;
my @cols_to_delete = grep { !$cols_of_interest{$_} } @cols;

my %csv_data;
while ( my $row = $csv->getline_hr(\*DATA) ) {
    delete @$row{@cols_to_delete};
    push @{ $csv_data{ $row->{dev_file} }{ "$row->{test_file}:$row->{diff_file}" } }, $row;
}
```

Comment: If I have to build a data structure as shown in post, I think the only possible way is to make a copy of %hash, right ? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: No, there's no need for three hashes. You can easily do this with just two, as I've shown in the newly-added section at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: I have updated my original post with additional code. Can you please let me know if my approach is the right one or is there a better way other than taking copy of reference.

Comment: Basically, declare variables as late as possible. Specifically, declare the hash inside the loop as I mentioned earlier. See addition to answer.